`grpc_tools_node_protoc` generated code does not build for `--moduleResolution=nodenext`
My Node.JS project uses --moduleResolution=nodenext. Code generation script:
"proto": "npx grpc_tools_node_protoc --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:./grpc/client --grpc_out=grpc_js:./grpc/client --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=`which grpc_tools_node_protoc_plugin` -I ./grpc/proto ./grpc/proto/*.proto && npx protoc --plugin=protoc-gen-ts=`which protoc-gen-ts` --ts_out=grpc_js:./grpc/client -I ./grpc/proto ./grpc/proto/*.proto",

Build errors:
grpc/client/response.ts:93:12 - error TS4114: This member must have an 'override' modifier because it overrides a member in the base class 'Message'.

93     static deserializeBinary(bytes: Uint8Array): Response {
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

grpc/client/response.ts:183:12 - error TS4114: This member must have an 'override' modifier because it overrides a member in the base class 'Message'.

183     static deserializeBinary(bytes: Uint8Array): Error {
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

grpc/client/school.ts:6:31 - error TS2835: Relative import paths need explicit file extensions in ECMAScript imports when '--moduleResolution' is 'node16' or 'nodenext'. Did you mean './student.js'?

6 import * as dependency_1 from "./student";
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~

grpc/client/school.ts:7:31 - error TS2835: Relative import paths need explicit file extensions in ECMAScript imports when '--moduleResolution' is 'node16' or 'nodenext'. Did you mean './teacher.js'?

7 import * as dependency_2 from "./teacher";
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~

grpc/client/school.ts:8:31 - error TS2835: Relative import paths need explicit file extensions in ECMAScript imports when '--moduleResolution' is 'node16' or 'nodenext'. Did you mean './response.js'?

8 import * as dependency_3 from "./response";
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~

grpc/client/school.ts:98:16 - error TS4114: This member must have an 'override' modifier because it overrides a member in the base class 'Message'.

98         static deserializeBinary(bytes: Uint8Array): RegisterRequest {
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

grpc/client/school.ts:191:16 - error TS4114: This member must have an 'override' modifier because it overrides a member in the base class 'Message'.

191         static deserializeBinary(bytes: Uint8Array): AddStudentsToTeacherRequest {
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

grpc/client/student.ts:163:16 - error TS4114: This member must have an 'override' modifier because it overrides a member in the base class 'Message'.

163         static deserializeBinary(bytes: Uint8Array): student {
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

grpc/client/teacher.ts:140:16 - error TS4114: This member must have an 'override' modifier because it overrides a member in the base class 'Message'.

140         static deserializeBinary(bytes: Uint8Array): teacher {
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 9 errors in 4 files.

Errors  Files
     2  grpc/client/response.ts:93
     5  grpc/client/school.ts:6
     1  grpc/client/student.ts:163
     1  grpc/client/teacher.ts:140
npm error Lifecycle script `build` failed with error:
npm error code 1
npm error path /usr/src/Node.JSRestAPI/src/webapi
npm error workspace webapi@1.0.0
npm error location /usr/src/Node.JSRestAPI/src/webapi
npm error command failed
npm error command sh -c tsc --project tsconfig.json && npm run rollup
ERROR: "build_webapi" exited with 1.

